# unsupported class version error in spark submit

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, java-8

Trying to run spark application which I build using maven and jdk1.8 on a remote machine in which installed Java version: jdk 1.7.
Using spark-submit command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class myapp.Main --master local[*] /home/mbala/myJars/CDCJar/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/mbala/myJars/CDCJar/previous.csv /home/mbala/myJars/CDCJar/source.csv /home/mbala/fer
```

Getting below exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myapp/Main : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:225)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:686)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Comment: The cause is exactly what you wrote in description, code compiled in java 8, run on java 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you build a `Java` program with a `Java Development Kit 8`, you need a `Java Runtime` **of at least 8** to be able to run it, otherwise you get this exception. Upgrade the version of java on your remote machine or build with a `JDK 7` instead to avoid such kind of issue.

Comment: the problem is that i set the jJAVA_HOME but whenever i logout then connect back i found it not set again

Comment: This may help for this problem http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42032/how-to-set-environment-variable-java-home-that-will-be-saved-on-exit

Comment: i tried this but i have to re-do it over over whenever i connect

Comment: there is something wrong on how you do it because once done, it is set automatically when you connect. What is the target os?

Comment: You can use a JDK 8 to compile your code and have it run on JDK 7. You have to set the target class file version, for example when using maven, set the property `<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi?rq=1